# pycurl only geting part of the response

Tags: python, json, pycurl

I'm making a request in python using pycurl to a URL which returns a reasonably large json formatted response. When I goto the URL in a browser I see the entire contents, but if I use pycurl and print the received data, I only see about half of what I see when I browse to the URL, and I get an error parsing the data using the json library stating :

> ValueError: Unterminated string starting at: line 1 column 16078 (char 16078)

The pycurl request is this :

```
conn = pycurl.Curl()
conn.setopt(pycurl.URL, myUrl)
conn.setopt(pycurl.WRITEFUNCTION, on_receive)
conn.setopt(pycurl.CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30)
conn.setopt(pycurl.TIMEOUT, 30)
conn.setopt(pycurl.NOSIGNAL, 10)
conn.perform()
```

with the on_receive function currently just printing the data.

Does anybody know why I am only getting part of the response? I have used massive timeouts just for trying to solve this, I had initially not specified any timeouts but was still getting this error.

Answer (score 1):

in pycurl, you could set this,

```
import pycurl
pycurl.CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD
```

try using

```
import Curl, pycurl
con = Curl()
con.set_option(pycurl.CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD, 9999999999)
con.get('url' ....
```

also try following until it works:

```
pycurl.SIZE_DOWNLOAD
pycurl.REQUEST_SIZE
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to access those json data with curl tool.
When you're able to get data, just translate curl options to pycurl options.

```
curl --help | less
```